# My Cipher Code is giving me a Floating Point Exception and i don't know why?

Tags: c, encryption

Hey so i'm a new programmer and i am taking a basic C course in college and we got assigned a project that implements an algorithm she gave us, that uses a Linear Congregational Generator (LCG) to encrypt and decrypt inputs.  She gave us a very detailed outline or code template but right now i am stuck with a Floating Point exception and i am guessing it involves my code in encrypt which is one of the last methods, but am unsure. I have removed the code template to make this post shorter but can post if needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* provides EXIT_SUCCESS */
#define DEBUG 0
#define MAP_LENGTH 28

enum cipherModeEnum {ENCRYPT, DECRYPT};
enum cipherModeEnum cipherMode;

/*
The different status codes are flags.
Since each is a power of 2, they can be turned on or off independently.
*/
int status;
const int CLEAR = 0;
const int OK = 1;
const int END_OF_LINE = 2;
const int END_OF_FILE = 4;
const int ERROR = 8;

unsigned long lcg_c;
unsigned long lcg_m;
unsigned long lcg_a;
unsigned long lcg_x;
int cipherMap[MAP_LENGTH];
int countForRPL = 0;
int inputLineNumber = 0;

/* this method will convert a character to a digit */
int charToDigit( char c )
{
  return c - '0';
}

int binToDec( int * binaryArray )
 {
   int value, i;
   value = 0;
   for( i = 0; i <= 8; i++ )
   {
    value = ( value << 1 ) | binaryArray[i];
   }
   return value;
 }


   unsigned long readPositiveLong(char delimiter)
{
  unsigned long digits;
  char c;
  int errorC, count, skipFirstChar;
  errorC = count = skipFirstChar = 0;
  while( c = getchar() )
  {
    if( skipFirstChar == 0 )
    {
      skipFirstChar++;
    }
    else
    {
      count++;
      if( countForRPL == 0 )
      {
        digits = digits * 10 + charToDigit(c);
        if( c == delimiter )
        {
          countForRPL == 1;
          break;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if( c == delimiter )
        {
          countForRPL = 0;
        }
      }
      if( c != '0' && c != '1' && c != '2' && c != '3' && c != '4' && c != '5' &&
          c != '6' && c != '7' && c != '8' && c != '9' && c != delimiter)
      {
        errorC = 1;
        break;
      }
      if( count > 20 )
      {
        errorC = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  if( errorC == 0 )
  {
    return digits;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
int setUniquePrimeFactors(unsigned long n, int prime[], int maxPrimes)
{
  int i, count;
  count = 0;
  for( i = 2; n > 1; i++ )
  {
    if( n % i == 0 )
    {
      while( n % i == 0 )
      {
        n /= i;
      }
      prime[count] = i;
      count++;
    }
  }
  if( count >= maxPrimes )
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    return count;
  }
}
unsigned long calculateLCG_a(unsigned long LCG_m)
{
  int prime[64] = { };
  unsigned long a, p;
  int i, count;
  a = p = count = 0;
  count = setUniquePrimeFactors(LCG_m, prime, 64);
  if( count = 0 )
  {
    return 0;
  }
  for( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
  {
    p = p * prime[i];
  }
  if( LCG_m % 4 == 0 )
  {
    a = 1+2*p;
  }
  else
  {
    a = 1+p;
  }
  if( a > 0 && a < LCG_m )
  {
    return a;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
void skipToEndOfLine(void)
{
  char c;
  while( c = getchar() )
  {
    if( c == '\n' )
    {
      status = END_OF_LINE;
      break;
    }
    if( c == EOF )
    {
      status = END_OF_FILE;
      break;
    }
  }
}
int readDataBlock(char data[])
{
  char c, twoByteChange;
  twoByteChange = '?';
  int place, dataSize, findData, count;
  place = dataSize = findData = count = 0;
  while( c = getchar() )
  {
    if( c == ',' )
    {
      findData++;
    }
    if( findData == 2 )
    {
      if( c == '\n' )
      {
        if( dataSize < 4 && dataSize > 0 )
        {
          int pad;
          for( pad = 0; pad < (5-dataSize); pad++ )
          {
            data[place] = '\0';
            place++;
          }
        }
        return END_OF_LINE;
      }
      if( c == EOF )
      {
        return END_OF_FILE;
      }
      if( cipherMode == ENCRYPT )
      {
        data[place] = c;
        place++;
        dataSize++;
      }
      if( cipherMode == DECRYPT )
      {
        if( count == 1 )
        {
          data[place] = c & twoByteChange;
          count = 0;
          place++;
          dataSize++;
        }
        if( c == '+' )
        {
          count = 1;
        }
        if( count = 0 )
        {
          data[place] = c;
          place++;
          dataSize++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return OK;
}
int readCipherMode(void)
{
  char c;
  c = getchar();
  if( c == 'e' )
  {
    cipherMode = ENCRYPT;
    return OK;
  }
  else if( c == 'd' )
  {
    cipherMode = DECRYPT;
    return OK;
  }
  else if( c == '\n' )
  {
    return END_OF_LINE;
  }
  else if( c == EOF )
  {
    return END_OF_FILE;
  }
  else
  {
    return ERROR;
  }
}
void buildMap(void)
{
  int count, countDown, i, used, usedCount;
  count = usedCount = 0;
  int g[MAP_LENGTH] = { };
  char free[28] =    {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27};
  for( i = 0; i < 28; i++ )
  {
    countDown = 28 - i;
    if( count == 0 )
    {
      lcg_x = lcg_m;
      g[i] = lcg_x % countDown;
      count = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      lcg_x = (( lcg_a * lcg_x + lcg_c ) % lcg_m );
      g[i] =  lcg_x % countDown;
    }
  }
  for( i = 0; i < 28; i++ )
  {
    for( used = 0; used < g[i]; used++ )
    {
      if( free[used] == 'u' )
        {
          usedCount++;
        }
    }
      cipherMap[i] = free[g[i]] + usedCount;
      free[g[i]] = 'u';
  }
}
int encrypt(char data[])
{
  int i, remainder, place;
  place = 0;
  char input = data[place];
  char binary[3] = "01";
  char digitsArray[28] = { };
  char binaryOutput[28] = { };
  int partOne[8] = { };
  int partTwo[8] = { };
  int partThree[8] = { };
  int partFour[8] = { };
  char output[8] = { };
  for( i = 7; i > 0; i-- )
  {
    remainder = input % 2;
    input = input/2;
    digitsArray[7-i] = binary[remainder];
  }
  place++;
  for( i = 14; i > 7; i-- )
  {
    remainder = input % 2;
    input = input/2;
    digitsArray[7-i] = binary[remainder];
  }
  place++;
  for( i = 20; i > 14; i-- )
  {
    remainder = input % 2;
    input = input/2;
    digitsArray[7-i] = binary[remainder];
  }
  place++;
  for( i = 27; i > 20; i-- )
  {
    remainder = input % 2;
    input = input/2;
    digitsArray[7-i] = binary[remainder];
  }
  for( i = 0; i < 28; i++ )
  {
    binaryOutput[cipherMap[i]] = digitsArray[i];
  }
  for( i = 7; i > 0; i-- )
  {
    partOne[i-1] = binaryOutput[7-i];
  }
  partOne[7] = '0';
  for( i = 14; i > 7; i-- )
  {
    partTwo[i-8] = binaryOutput[14-i];
  }
  partTwo[7] = '0';
  for( i = 20; i > 14; i-- )
  {
    partThree[i-15] = binaryOutput[20-i];
  }
  partThree[7] = '0';
  for( i = 27; i > 20; i-- )
  {
     partFour[i-21] = binaryOutput[27-i];
  }
  partFour[7] = '0';
  output[0] = binToDec(partOne);
  output[1] = binToDec(partTwo);
  output[2] = binToDec(partThree);
  output[3] = binToDec(partFour);
  printf("%5d) %s\n", inputLineNumber, output);
}
int main()
{

  int inputLineNumber = 0;
  status = CLEAR;

  char data[5];
  data[4] = '\0';

  while (status != END_OF_FILE)
  {
    status = CLEAR;
    inputLineNumber++;

    status = readCipherMode();

    if (DEBUG) printf("readCipherMode::mode=%d status=%d\n",cipherMode,status);

    if ((status & END_OF_FILE) == 0)
    {
      printf("%5d) ", inputLineNumber);
    }
    if (status == OK)
    {
      status = readKey();
      if (DEBUG)
    {
      printf ("\tKey: m=%lu c=%lu a=%lu x=%lu status=%d\n",
               lcg_m, lcg_c, lcg_a, lcg_x, status);
     }
    }

    while (status == OK)
    {
      buildMap();
      status = readDataBlock(data);
      if (DEBUG) printf("\treadDataBlock::data=%s status=%d\n",data,status);
      if ((status & ERROR) == 0)
      {
        if (cipherMode == ENCRYPT) status |= encrypt(data);
        else status |= decrypt(data);
      }
   }

    if (status & ERROR)
    {
      puts("Error");
      skipToEndOfLine();
    }
    else puts("");
 }
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

I have not created or started the decrypt code yet because i dont see why my encrypt code is not working, i know it doesn't look great but this is the best i could come up with, with my coding knowledge.

Comment: Where is this exception occurring?

Comment: Also, how are you calling this? There is no main function even though you have posted a lot of code.

Comment: Use `gdb` or `printf` debugging and find the section of code (or exact line of code) where it is giving exception. Also in your posted code there is not a single `float` variable or cast then how is it giving `Floating Point exception`

Comment: The name "Floating-point exception" is a bit of a misnomer. In my experience, float divisions by zero usually result in infinities, but integer divisions by zero lead to a FPE. My guess would be that the modulo on the global `lcg_m` in `BuildMap` is the culprit. That variable is not initialized and never assigned a value in the posted code, so it might well be zero.

Comment: hey just added the main code , and i assigned lcg_m in readkey()

Comment: and i am figuring out how to use gdb right now so when i figure out the lines ill post it

Comment: if someone could explain how to use gbd i am not completly sure what i am looking for in the printed stuff from gbd

Comment: Compile your program with the `-g` flag. Then start the debugger with `gdb progname`. Inside gdb, run the program with `run` and enter all stuff as usual. (I assume that you read input from the terminal.) Eventually your program will raise the FPE and execution of the program in gdb will stop. It will tell you the line number where the FPE occured. You can type `where` to see a call stack, i.e. a list of routines that lead to the call of the present routine. You can walk through the call stack with `up` and `down`. You can also try to look at stuff with `print lcg_m`.

Comment: Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x0000000000400786 in setUniquePrimeFactors (n=7818741776187847, prime=0x7fffffffe950, maxPrimes=64) at cipher.c:156
156 if( n % i == 0 )
this is what i got, and also i am using maxprimes as a basic 64, i know that is not the actual maxprimes of the number but i dont think it would affect it much

Comment: Also my input was e126,25,Byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to find the prime factors of a `long` by checking the remainder after a division by an `int`. Your number is a prime, so you can't divied it by any number in the range of normal `int`s, which usually is -2147483648 to 2147483647. When you hit the max value, your increment `i++` wraps (like an odometer) to the min value an eventually ends up being zero. Bang! You should make your local `i` also an `unsigned long`.

That will present you with another problem: Your prime factorisation is okay for non-primes and small primes. It will take the full 7818741776187847 loops to get `n` down to 1. (You can make a rough estimation for fun by optimistically assuming that a very fast processor can treat 1G loops in a second. Your factorisation will take about 90 days.)

To cater for such edge case, you could do a primality check first:

```
int is_prime(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long m;

    if (n % 2 == 0) return 0;

    for (m = 3; m*m <= n; m+= 2) {
        if (n % m == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

That's not fast, but can be done in finite time.

By the way, you have an error in how you treat the array size `maxPrimes`: When you check this array bound, you have already populated your array, possibly overflowing the buffer `prime`. You should check the buffer size in the loop, after you have increased `count`.

Comment: Hey just got back from my cs lab, i totally misunderstood how getchar works so ignore that but i did get to implement this isprime into my code and changed i to be a unsinged long, running it now dont know how long it will take so ill respond when it does

Comment: oh and how do i check this buffer size?, also to add to this i figured out i have a infinite loop somewhere inside my code or well the part that is declaring what lcg_m is so i will need to find this first, thanks and ill let you know how it works

Comment: Thank you that pretty much fixed it

Comment: You don't have an infinite loop, just a loop that happens to take a very long time. Your method doesn't work well with the input you have. That's why I proposed an additional primality check. That will slow down the overall code, but will catch the edge case of huge primes. (You don't show how you call `calculateLCG_a`, so I don't know what kind of input you can expect.)

Comment: About the range check: Place your check after incrementing `count` inside the loop: `if (count >= maxPrimes) return 0`. After the loop, return `count` unconditionally. But let's play another estimating game: The smallest number that has 64 unique prime factors is `2*3*5*7*...*307*311`. This is a number with 126 decimal digits or 417 binary digits (bits). Which certainly won't fit into a 64-bit `long` integer. For a 64 bit usigned long, you should be safe with a buffer length of 16, which will hold `2*3*5*...*47*53`. Buffer overflow is the least of your concerns.

Comment: Thanks and ya i implented pretty much what you just said and i got everything working just a little more to go